# Blue screen when attempting to reinstall Mavericks using USB

Tags: macos, install

I recently formatted my MacBook and used another MacBook Pro to create a bootable USB. Now, when I try to reinstall Mavericks on my Mac using the bootable USB, I get a blue screen in the process.

Comment: Hi, did you check your drive and the USB

Comment: @Buscar Could you expand on how you intend the user to do this? — Sheriff, could you explain in more detail at what point in the process the blue screen shows?

Comment: Is your MacBook supported by Mavericks?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to make sure your MacBook is supported by Mavericks. Check [this page here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5842) to make sure.

**UPDATE**

OK, having checked that it is supported by Mavericks but that it does not install from the USB, you have a few options. None of them is particularly straightforward, but here goes:

1. Burn a DVD and boot from that. This is probably going to have the same results as the USB drive, but it takes any USB-related issues out of the equation.
2. Boot into Internet Recovery mode (hold <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, power on and keep <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> pressed until it starts to boot in recovery mode). Select the option to install the OS from there.
3. If both Macs have Firewire, put the MacBook into Target mode, connect the two machines, and run the installer on the MacBook Pro, specifying the MacBook's hard disk as the target for the installer. This will install OK, as long as the MacBook Pro is also supported by Mavericks.
4. Take the hard disk out of the MacBook and put it into the MacBook Pro. Install Mavericks on the MacBook Pro, then swap the hard disk back again. Once more - the MacBook Pro must be supported by Mavericks for this to work.

Good luck!

Comment: what would be the second step if it does support Mavericks?

Comment: @Buscar There is no second step? If this is the cause of the blue screen then the cause has been discovered and the problem solved.

Comment: So your answer is bit misleading "The first step is"?